# UserPermissions required to use Core Service?

Tags: core-service, c#

This code works nicely when I have "Administrator" privileges...

```
string item = "tcm:12-31-64";
if (this.client.IsExistingObject(item))
{
    this.client.Read(item, new ReadOptions(););
}
```

...but when I do not, the `IsExistingOject` call succeeds, but the `Read` call fails.

My system administrator does not want me to have "Administrator" priviliges just to use Core Service.  I can successfully read the item through a browser, so it seems the missing privileges are between "accessing through browser" and "accessing through Core Service.

Any ideas what the additional permissions required are?  Is there a built-in group(s) I need to be a part of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The access should be the same if it's the same user. What's the error and what do you do with the returned `IdentifiableObjectData`? I'd look at confirming permissions for the containing structure group and maybe checking it's the right item, publication, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have not impersonated the Core service client call with your `Identity`.

As per my experience, I won't suggest to use administrator access to impersonate and do processing the request.

### Example:

```
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient ProxyClient = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("wsHttp_2011");
ProxyClient.Impersonate(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```